# Loading contents of a plist crashes one out of "many" times when running

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, dictionary, plist

I have a function that loads the contents of a plist:

```
func loadSecretDataFromPlist() -> [String: String]? {
    if let path = Bundle.main.path(forResource: "SecretData", ofType: "plist") {
        if let commonDict = NSDictionary(contentsOfFile: path) {
            return (commonDict as! [String : String])
        }
    }

    return nil
}
```

I then have a singleton class that calls this function to load this data:

```
final class ClassA {
    static var sharedInstance = ClassA()
    var secretData = loadSecretDataFromPlist()!
    // ... more functions and stuff below
}
```

Most of the time (like 19/20), it runs as expected. But every now and then, it causes the app to crash on the 4th line of the function, which is `return (commonDict as! [String: String])`

The console error is `Failed to inherit CoreMedia permissions from 49868: (null) (lldb)`

Not really sure why or how this is happening :/

Answer (score 0):

I would initialize `secretData` lazily and use `PropertyListSerialization`

```
final class ClassA {

    static let sharedInstance = ClassA()

    lazy var secretData : [String:String] = {
        let url = Bundle.main.url(forResource: "SecretData", withExtension: "plist")!
        let data = try! Data(contentsOF: url)
        return try! PropertyListSerialization.propertyList(from: data, format: nil) as! [String:String]
    }()
}
```

The benefit is that the data is read **once** when the property is accessed the first time

Comment: isn't the data still read once when calling the function since it's a singleton?

Comment: No, the singleton itself is loaded lazily but this behavior doesn't affect `secretData`. Try it out: Add `print` lines